# Can any one explain this codes to me? Creating a custom layout control

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

can anyone explain me these codes what are they doing exactly? I could not understand how it is adding two buttons (OK and Cancel). I expect some button creation code like `new Button()` or something like that It is accessing the buttons with id but there are no button with these ids in any xml file. I can just see the `R.id.okcancelbar_ok` defination in R file.

Thanks.

Original source : http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html

Source Code : http://progx.org/users/Gfx/android/MergeLayout.zip

```
public class OkCancelBar extends LinearLayout {
    public OkCancelBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
        setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        setWeightSum(1.0f);
                LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.okcancelbar, this, true);
                TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.OkCancelBar, 0, 0);
                String text = array.getString(R.styleable.OkCancelBar_okLabel);
        if (text == null) text = "Ok";
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.okcancelbar_ok)).setText(text);
                text = array.getString(R.styleable.OkCancelBar_cancelLabel);
        if (text == null) text = "Cancel";
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.okcancelbar_cancel)).setText(text);
                array.recycle();
    }}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.okcancelbar, this, true);
```

this line inflate "this" with the layout R.layout.okcancelbar

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.okcancelbar_ok)).setText(text)
```

it means that there is a button with id "okcancelbar_ok" in the layout okcancelbar ( inflated earlier)
Next we assigned to it the text "Ok"

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.okcancelbar_cancel)).setText(text);
```

same as above, there is a button with id "okcancelbar_cancel" in the layout okcancelbar

So this code do :
1) inflate the view R.layout.okcancelbar
2) get the button (declared in the previous layout) with id "okcancelbar_ok" and set the text to "Ok"
3) idem with the button "okcancelbar_cancel" and text "Cancel"

The "layout/okcancelbar.xml" layout should be like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <include
        layout="@layout/okcancelbar_button"
        android:id="@+id/okcancelbar_ok" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/okcancelbar_button"
        android:id="@+id/okcancelbar_cancel" />
</merge>
```

There also should be a "values/attrs.xml" that looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="OkCancelBar">
    <attr name="okLabel" format="string"/>
    <attr name="cancelLabel" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

And finally the "layout/okcancelbar_button" should looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/button"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">    
</Button>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: the problem is there is no such thing with "okcancelbar_ok" id. I was expecting a okcancelbar.xml under the layout folder but it is not exist. Did you check the zip file and files in it?

Comment: there is not, but it's just "a new view called OkCancelBar which simply shows two buttons with customizable labels". I think this project with no modification should not compile because this layout is missing.

Comment: OK than can you give me an example about the missing layout. 
I think this is not ok. there should be xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" parametre.
<xml.... />
<button id=OKbutton>
<button id=Cancenbutton>

Answer (score 0):

The above is almost enough to get turn the messed-up *MergedLayout.zip* into a usable project.

There were only 2 details I found to fix:

1. In `layout/okcancelbar_button.xml` (the name of course ends with .xml),
   substitute `wrap_content` for `fill_parent`.  With `fill_parent` one of the buttons covers the other.
2. The file `src/com/example/android/merge/R.java` is included in the *MergedLayout.zip*

It should be deleted