# Merge layout sourcecode does not work?

Tags: android, layout, merge

Is there anyone that could get  the MergeLayout source code worked which is an article published in android dev website. the link below?

[Here is the link](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html)

I would appreciate that if you can have a look and see the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the error you are receiving?

Comment: Too many errors :) I think its not well designed! BEcause When I get the source code I get 3 classes and only one main.xml layout. However  in the class OkCancelBar there are layouts called okcancelbar which doesnt exist. Basically I cant run it because there are many things missing in the code. I searched and found another website published the same code exactly the same there and people ask the same questions. there is no answer unfortunately..

Comment: See this post.  The source is missing lots of layout xml.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411610/can-any-one-explain-this-codes-to-me-creating-a-custom-layout-control

Answer (score 2):

The content of the missing okcancelbar.xml file is in the article:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <include
        layout="@layout/okcancelbar_button"
        android:id="@+id/okcancelbar_ok" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/okcancelbar_button"
        android:id="@+id/okcancelbar_cancel" />
</merge>
```

Comment: Thank you. There is another thing is missin is that when I add this xml layout. it complains about the layout okcancelbar_button? should I create another xml layout for it? what about the code goes in that file?

Comment: Just put a Button in that file.

Comment: it still generates error in this file that okcancelbar_button is not valid even though I created the okcancelbar_button.xml and place 2 buttons with the id okcancelbar_ok and okcancelbar_cancel what else I should do:(